# How can I pass the state (useState hook) between pages in React 18 / Next.js 13

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js13

Can someone advice how should I pass the React state form page in dir "/reminders" to page in dir "/reminders/overview/[id]"  so that the state can be use by function "deleteReminder" passed to this page ?

The is case described below :

Here is a simplify project dir and files tree:

`/lib`

`test_data.ts`
    `deleteReminder.ts`
    `ReminderComponent.tsx`
`/app`
    `app/reminders`
        `page.tsx`
        `app/reminders/overview/[id]`
            `page.tsx`

Here is a code of each file

lib/test_data.ts

```
    export default TEST_DATA: Reminder[] = [ 
        {
            id: "1",
            content: "test1"
        },
        {
            id: "2",
            content: "test2",
        },
    ]
```

lib/deleteReminder.ts

```
    import React from "react";

    interface Reminder {
        id: string;
        content: string;
    }

    const deleteReminder = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>, id: string, reminders: Reminder[], setReminders: Function) =>{
        event.stopPropagation();
        event.preventDefault();
        const updateReminders = reminders.filter((reminder) => {
            return reminder.id !== id
        })
        setReminders(updatedReminders)
    }

    export default deleteReminder;
```

lib/ReminderComponent.tsx

```
    import React from "react";
    import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";

    interface ComponentProps {
        key: string;
        id: string;
        content: string;
        deleteReminder: Function;  
        reminders: Reminder[];
        setReminders: Function;
    }

    export default function ReminderComponent(props: componentProps) {

        const router = useRounter();
        const navigateToOverview = () =>  router.push(`reminders/overview/${props.id}`);
    
        return(
            <div onClick = {() => navigateToOverview} >
                <div>
                    {props.content}    
                </div>
                <button onClick = {(e) => props.deleteReminder(e, props.id, props.reminders, props.setReminders)}>
                    delete reminder
                </button>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

app/reminders/page.tsx

```
    import { useState } React from "react";
    import { TEST_DATA } from "@/lib/test_data"
    import deleteReminder from "@/lib/deleteReminder";
    import ReminderComponent from "@/lib/deleteReminder";

    interface Reminder {
    id: string;
    content: string;
    }

    export default function RemindersPage() {

        // this is the state I want to pass to app/reminders/overview/[id]
        const [reminders, setReminders] = React.useState(TEST_DATA); 
        
        return(
            <div>
            {reminders.map((reminder) => (
                <ReminderComponent
                    key = {reminder.key}
                    id = {reminder.id}
                    content = {reminder.content}
                    deleteReminder = {deleteReminder}
                    reminders = {reminders}
                    setReminders = {setReminders} 
                />
            ))}
            </div>
        )  
    }
```

app/reminders/overview/[id]/page.tsx

```
    import { useState } React from "react";
    import { useRouter } from "next/navigation"
    import { TEST_DATA } from "@/lib/test_data"
    import deleteReminder from "@/lib/deleteReminder";

    interface pageProps {
        params: {id: string};
    }

    export default function OverviewPage ({params}: PageProps) {
        const router = useRouter();
        const navigateBack = () => router.back();

        if (TEST_DATA){
            const reminder = TEST_DATA.find((element) => element.id === params.id);
            if (reminder === undefined) {
                throw new Error ('error')
            }
            return reminder;
        }
    
        return (
            <div>
                <div>
                    {reminder.content}
                </div>
                <button onClick = {(e) => {
                    // here I want to use state (reminders and setReminders) //
                    deleteReminder(e, params.id, reminders, setReminders);
                    navigateBack;
                }}> 
                delete
                </button>  
            </div>
        )
    }
```

As you can see there is no componenet connecting these two pages where we can pass state as a props.
I will be glad for your recomendation about best practice how can I have acces to the this state on reminders/overview/[id] page to use it in function deleteReminder.

Answer (score -1):

To pass the React state from the page in the directory **/reminders** to the page in the directory **/reminders/overview/[id]** and use that state in the **deleteReminder** function, you can follow these steps:

1. **Pass State via Next.js Router:**

You can pass state between pages using Next.js router. In your RemindersPage, you need to use **useRouter** and **useEffect** to navigate to the overview page with the state you want to pass. Here's an updated **RemindersPage**:

```
import { useState, useEffect } React from "react";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import { TEST_DATA } from "@/lib/test_data";
import deleteReminder from "@/lib/deleteReminder";
import ReminderComponent from "@/lib/ReminderComponent"; // Fix import

interface Reminder {
  id: string;
  content: string;
}

export default function RemindersPage() {
  const [reminders, setReminders] = React.useState(TEST_DATA);
  const router = useRouter();

  // Use useEffect to navigate to the overview page with state
  const navigateToOverview = (id: string) => {
    router.push(`/reminders/overview/${id}`, undefined, { shallow: true });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {reminders.map((reminder) => (
        <ReminderComponent
          key={reminder.id} // Use 'id' instead of 'key' as the key
          id={reminder.id}
          content={reminder.content}
          deleteReminder={deleteReminder}
          navigateToOverview={navigateToOverview} // Pass the navigation function
        />
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

2. **Receive State in OverviewPage:**

In the **OverviewPage**, you can access the state passed via the router and then use it in your **deleteReminder** function. Here's an updated **OverviewPage**:

```
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import deleteReminder from "@/lib/deleteReminder";

// Other imports

export default function OverviewPage() {
  const router = useRouter();
  const { id } = router.query; // Get the 'id' from the query

  if (!id) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }

  const reminder = TEST_DATA.find((element) => element.id === id);

  if (!reminder) {
    throw new Error("Error");
  }

  const { reminders, setReminders } = router.query; // Get state from query

  return (
    <div>
      <div>{reminder.content}</div>
      <button
        onClick={(e) => {
          deleteReminder(e, id, reminders, setReminders);
          router.back(); // Fix: Call navigateBack function
        }}
      >
        delete
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: `const { reminders, setReminders } = router.query; // Get state from query` -> where did you get this information from?

Comment: This solution doesn't make sense